# How to set up IDbConnectionFactory to be autowired/injected when not inheriting Service?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, servicestack, funq

How to set up IDbConnectionFactory to be autowired/injected when not inheriting Service?

I some repository class that will be used in another repository class, but not inheriting from the Service class. it look like this:

```
public class UsersControlSettingsRepository
{
    //Property should be injected, but still null
    public IDbConnectionFactory Conn { get; set; } 
    public UsersControlSettings GetUsersSettings()
    {
        using (var _db = Conn.Conn.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            return _db.Select<UsersControlSettings>()
                .OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the apphost config:

```
var conn = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlaBla"].ConnectionString, 
    MySqlDialect.Provider);

container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
Container.RegisterValidators(typeof(MainServices).Assembly);

container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => conn);

container.Register(c => new UsersControlSettingsRepository()
{
    Conn = c.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()
});
```

And then, I use the class like this:

```
public class AuthExtended : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    private readonly Md5 _hashing;
    private Users _user;
    private UsersControlSettings _userSettings;

    private readonly UsersRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly UsersControlSettingsRepository _controlSettings;
    public AuthExtended()
    {
        _hashing = new Md5();
        _userSettings= EndpointHost.AppHost
            .TryResolve<UsersControlSettingsRepository>();
    }
```

Am I doing Something Wrong in here?

Comment: How are you creating your `UsersControlSettingsRepository`? If you are just new'ing one up then you will not have anything injected, you should be resolving it using the container. i.e. `EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<UsersControlSettingsRepository>();`

Comment: Yes, I tried both of them and no luck, I update my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your examples I believe the `AuthExtended` class is being created before you have registered your various classes with the container. If the `AuthExtended` constructor is called before the `UserControlSettingsRepository` has been registered it will not be resolved. Check the `Configure` method of your AppHost to see if you are creating the provider before you register your repository.

Here's a quick 1-file ServiceStack console application to demonstrate:

```
public interface IFakeDbConnectionFactory
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public class FakeDbConnectionFactory : IFakeDbConnectionFactory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UsersControlSettingsRepository {
    public IFakeDbConnectionFactory Conn { get; set; }        
}

public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Test App", typeof (AppHost).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        var conn = new FakeDbConnectionFactory { Name = "TestDB1"};
        container.Register<IFakeDbConnectionFactory>(c => conn);

        container.Register(c => new UsersControlSettingsRepository {
            Conn = c.TryResolve<IFakeDbConnectionFactory>()
        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new AppHost();
        app.Init();
        app.Start(@"http://+:8085/");
        var repo = EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<UsersControlSettingsRepository>();
        Console.WriteLine(repo.Conn.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here's an example of an app host that registers the database information and *then* ceratse the authentication provider:

```
public class MyApphost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public MyApphost() : base("Service Name", typeof(MyApphost).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        // Register database connection before creating a provider...
        var conn = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlaBla"].ConnectionString, MySqlDialect.Provider);

        Container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        Container.RegisterValidators(typeof(MainServices).Assembly);
        Container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => conn);
        Container.Register(c => new UsersControlSettingsRepository() {
            Conn = c.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()
        });

        // Setup authentication
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider()}
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it not instantiated. so what I should do to get it registered?

Comment: Added another example to show registering the proper classes before creating the provider.